# Topbar on mobile clogged: here’re some suggestions

Tags: feature-request, design, top-bar, responsive-design

Below you can see how topbar looks on mobile currently:

[image: don’t enter image description here]

Oh sorry, wrong photo

[image]

There was a question regarding topbar overflow. I’d like to go slightly further:

1. “home” not needed, since the logo* (“META” and corresponding ones on other sites) already linked to the homepage
2. teams could be moved to the button with my communities (btw, is there’re any need for the teams button to be present anywhere outside stack overflow?)
3. Other items in the hamburger menu could go somewhere under the topbar. I mean, why there’re two steps to get to the questions? It’s not convenient
4. regarding Stack Exchange logo: it serves “about us” purpose and features the button that goes to all communities, which is also present in the dropdown with “my communities” and could be moved up to a more visible position. As for the “about us” purpose, I don’t think there’s a need in it. If a person has a question, he presses the button with question mark.

---

*- I mean this logo:

[image]

Comment: This doesn't leave room for SO's "Products" menu, arguably the most useful button in the nav bar.

Comment: @kevin SO is different, my question is mostly about any communities except SO

Comment: The logo does not go to the home page outside of SO itself.

Comment: Clearly a design flaw, as that's where all logos should go.

Comment: @KevinB The logo isn't for the site, it's for the network, though? Except on SO.

Comment: A link to the home page of the site you're on, is clearly more important than one to the network... Why are they reversed?

Comment: @Catija regarding logo, updated question for clarity

Comment: Finally I get to see @nicael posting while I'm participating on MSE. I'm not sure if I understand those scribbles on the screenshots but I'm sure it's brilliant!

Comment: They even manage to fit in more things when you're a moderator: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fHu4w.jpg - I'm wondering how it will look like with Winterbash ...