# Let us add custom Bookmarks/Links to the sidebar

Tags: feature-request, sidebar

Teams are going to be removed from the sidebar. I don't understand why SE is doing this (I understand separating Teams from SO, but you can do that without removing it from the sidebar), but it seems like SE has made up their mind about this.

The sidebar never had enough content to justify the space it takes up, and now it'll be even less useful. And SE has never gotten anywhere with the various ideas of putting other things into the sidebar, with the exception of Teams and Collectives. So let's turn this around and let the users decide what they want in their sidebar.

Give users the ability to add their own links to the sidebar. This could be e.g. another SE site, a specific review queue, a mod tool or a Teams link. Or a link to a specific search on one SE site.

I'm intentionally making this as simple as it can be, it is a URL and a short user-chosen name (so that it can't overflow the sidebar). No activity indicator or anything dynamic. It would be nice to be able to add SE icons in front of the name, but that's optional.

There is plenty of space in the sidebar, and has for years. SE doesn't seem to have anything they want to put in there, so let the users fill that space themselves.

Comment: they also use it for company profiles, which honestly I've never quite seen the use of

Comment: While we're at it, make the whole damn page responsive as well. SE uses only half of my screen right now, with only half of that being actual content.

Comment: they have a wierd hang up about content being too wide :D

Comment: The [top design user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/377593) sort of preempted the ideas that were soon to come. I'm not surprised folks don't consider https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_space